# Python regex no output

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use regex to get the url from the text file. And I am taking XML in the form of .txt format 
My text file is locations.txt. This is the text file

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below. 
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

<sitemap> 
<loc>https://www.apple.com/jp/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc>  </sitemap>
 <sitemap>
 <loc>https://www.apple.com/ph/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc>
</sitemap> 
<sitemap>
 <loc>https://www.apple.com/hk-zh/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc>
 </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/kr/shop/sitemap-      index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/nz/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/th/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/sg/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/au/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/my/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/tw/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/cn/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/hk/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/be-nl/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/it/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/lu/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/hu/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/at/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/cz/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/fi/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/tr/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/de/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/es/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/ie/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/pl/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/se/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/ae/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/be-fr/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap> <loc>https://www.apple.com/dk/shop/sitemap-index.xml</loc> </sitemap> <sitemap>
```

The script I am using :

```
import re
re.findall('<(loc)>(https?://)([^\s]+)(</\1>)', open('locations.txt', 'r').read())
```

But there is no output.

Comment: **1.** "I am trying to use regex to get the url from the text file" should be fixed to "I am trying to use regex to get the url from XML file", and **2.** Don't use regex to parse XML files. Use proper XML parsers.

Comment: @DeepSpace  what if it is in the text format and not in xml format ?

Comment: @emon what do you mean? What is the difference between those except the file extension? Take a look if the [`ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module can help you.

Comment: @Bit Okay ! that's cool . But what if i want to use regex. Can anything be done here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do not use regular expressions to parse XML files (or any hierarchical/nested structures)
2. [**DO NOT USE REGULAR EXPRESSIONS TO PARSE XML FILES**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7553525)
3. If you insist to pick up content between the nearest `<loc>` and `</loc>`tags with regex:

.

```
import re

with open("locations.txt", 'r') as f:
    locations = re.findall(r"<loc>(https?\S+)</loc>", f.read())
    # ['https://www.apple.com/jp/shop/sitemap-index.xml',
    #  'https://www.apple.com/ph/shop/sitemap-index.xml',
    #  'https://www.apple.com/hk-zh/shop/sitemap-index.xml', ...]
```

Yours fails mostly because you're not escaping your backslashes, but even if you did you'd be getting three more groups instead of just the URL.